# The image under mapping $w=(z+i)/(z-i)$, of the third quadrant?

Tags: complex-analysis, transformation, conformal-geometry

The title says it all. I am not sure how to approach this problem. The only related problems i have done is mapping a (unbounded)line /circle to a line/circle.

Regards
Exatic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints:**

- The third quadrant is bounded by the $x,y$ axes.
- Möbius transformation preserve orientation, in the sense that the region to the left (right) of the line/circle is mapped onto the region to the left (right) of the line/circle in the image.

Comment: Okay so if we take the y axes first. It clearly goes through zero in denominator, and hence must map to a line. By trying the points. w(-i)=0, and w(0)=-1, it must be the real axis.

I'm not sure from here how to find the mapping of the x-axis. I know it's going to be a circle, but how no idea how to find it.

Comment: @Exatic That's a great start. As for the $x$ axis consider the points $0,1,\infty$; they are mapped to $-1,i,1$. Which circle is determined by them?

Comment: The unit circle. And by taking w(-(1+i)) = -(1+2i)/5, which must be the lower half of the unit circle. Thanks a lot! I have a follow-up question: How can i generalize the way to find from a line to a circle? I have a similar problem where i need to find the image of the mapping w=$\frac{1}{z}$ where Im z = 1, and i know i can try with the point i, but not sure of the two others.

Comment: @Exatic As you remarked before, the image will be a straight line iff the denominator vanishes. $i$ is indeed a convenient choice,  and $\infty$ lies on the line as well. From the symmetry of the problem these map into the two endpoints of a diameter. From there you can determine the radius.

Comment: I'm sorry i don't quite follow with the $\infty$. Could you elaborate, or show how you're thinking? :)

Comment: @Exatic Well, every (infinite) line contains the points at infinity. Recall that in the "Riemann sphere" model all directional infinites such as $+\infty, -\infty,i \infty, \dots$ are viewed as the same point - the point at infinity.

Comment: Thanks alot again! :) So r will be |i-0|/2 = 1/2. I see in the solution the circle is also translated 1/2 (|w-1/2| <= 1/2). How did they find that?

Comment: @Exatic Are you sure? I think it's wrong

Comment: I'm sorry it is the solution for $(z-i)/z$, which maps i, $\infty$ to 0 and 1, and finally makes sense. I'm very grateful for your help!